# How to write to a spreadsheet in python3.2?

Tags: python, excel, csv, module, python-3.2

I am currently writing a script where I want to take the data and write it to a spreadsheet. I've found a few modules for writing xls files, however those only seem to work up to python 2.x, and I'm using 3.2 (also on a mac if that's helpful). Anyone have any ideas on how to get a python3.2 script to output to a spreadsheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **[csv](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/csv.html)** module.  The intro from the docs:

> The csv module implements classes to read and write tabular data in
>   CSV format. It allows programmers to say, “write this data in the
>   format preferred by Excel,” or “read data from this file which was
>   generated by Excel,” without knowing the precise details of the CSV
>   format used by Excel. Programmers can also describe the CSV formats
>   understood by other applications or define their own special-purpose
>   CSV formats.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can use the COM interface:  http://users.rcn.com/python/download/quoter.pyw

As @sdolan pointed out, CSV can be a good choice if your data is laid out in a tabular format.

Since Excel can save spreadsheets in an XML format, you can use XML tools to access the data.

Comment: I don't use windows, mac and linux solutions would be good for me. And I'll go the CSV route since CSV's are incredibly useful and always a good bet. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @rab777hp: beware: CSV is *not* standard, so one can easily run into problems, if the cells contain more complex data (like strings containing newlines, or commas, or quotes, etc.).